# Unable to understand results of Python code

Tags: python

I was learning about dictionaries in Python and I created a simple program:

```
# Create an empty dictionary called d1
d1 = {}

# Print dictionary and length
def dixnary():
    print "Dictionary contents : "
    print d1
    print "Length = ", len(d1)

# Add items to dictionary
d1["to"] = "two"
d1["for"] = "four"

print "Dictionary contents :"
print d1
print "Length =" , len(d1)

# Print dictionary and length
print dixnary()
```

Now there's a difference in the results when I use the `print` commands and when I use the `dixnary` function.

Using the `print` commands I get the result:

> Dictionary contents:
>   <'to':'two','for:'four'>
>   Length = 2

and when I use the function `dixnary`, I get the results:

> Dictionary contents:
>   <'to':'two','for:'four'>
>   Length = 2
>   None

Notice the `None` on the final line. This `None` gets added when I use the function `dixnary`. Why is this?

Comment: What does `dixnary()` return? That's the last thing you're printing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're attempting to print the return value of a function, but the function doesn't return a value, so it returns the default value of None.

The reason why it prints out other data is that you have print commands inside of the function.  Just run the function (`dixnary()`), instead of printing it (`print dixnary()`).

Or alternatively, have the program return the string, so you can do useful things with it.

```
def dixnary():
    return "Dictionary contents :\n%s\nLength = %d" % (d1, len(d1))

print dixnary()
```

Comment: Umm, you are actually wrong.
I was only using the functions earlier and was getting the result with NOne in it.
Therefore I added the print commands
to see whether they give the same results
and I found that results were different.
Have you tried this program?
Maybe use a # in front of the print commands
and you will see that the function still gives the results.

Comment: No, I'm really not... You're printing out the return value of the function, which isn't returning a value, so it defaults to None.  I promise you.  If something's unclear I can try to explain better.

Comment: Please do not ask a question and then tell people they're wrong when they answer... especially when they are right :) You haven't understood: the function does all the printing normally, and then returns a value `None`. You wrote code that calls the function, and then prints the value returned from the function. That is what the line `print dixnary()` does. If you didn't want to print the `None`, then you should just have `dixnary()`. Try that yourself.

Comment: Aha! Yes, it worked. I hadn't understood earlier. Sorry for saying you are wrong.
But I dont understand why this is happening.
What is meant by value returned from the function?
and how is it different when I just use dixnary() ?

Comment: Sorry for the lull, function take argument, do actions then return a variable (optionally).  In python, if a function does not return a variable explicitly, it implicitly returns the None object.  When you `print` a function, what you're actually `print`ing is the return value of the function.

Comment: aha! I think I get it. Thanks. You were very helpful.